# How to set innnerhtml content to html section background image url

Tags: javascript, html

Have to set innnerhtml content to html section background image url. I have tried so many ways but somthing is missing... he is the code...

```
function handle_setVals(xhr) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
         var data = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
         if (data['1']){
                   document.getElementById('f_bgimg_1').innerHTML = './images/' + data['1']['f_back_ground_PC'];

         }
    }
}
```

in html...

```
<section id="result2-page" class="fullsize-page result2" style=background-image: url()>
</section>
```

wan to set f_bgimg_1 to background-image: url()..
i have tried hidden varibale and like this too

```
<section id="result2-page" class="fullsize-page result2" style=background-image: url(<span id='f_bgimg_1'></span>)>
</section>
```

not working... thank in advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `setAttribute` method to set a new style in the `section` tag:

```
document.getElementById("result2-page").setAttribute("style", "background-image: url()");
```

e.g.:

```js
(function() {
  var image = "http://mygimptutorial.com/images/button-with-reflection/11.jpg";
  document.getElementById("result2-page").setAttribute("style", "background-image: url(" + image + ")");
})();
```

```css
.result2 {
  display: block;
  height: 169px;
  width: 498px;
}
```

```html
<section id="result2-page" class="fullsize-page result2">
</section>
```